# How to trigger an socket.io from server-side to server-side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I know this sounds basic, but I apparently cannot find this in the api doc,
http://socket.io/docs/server-api/

what I have currently is front-end doing `#emit` and `on` for server-side code, and vice-versa.

What I am looking for is a `socket#trigger` function that triggers an event I made already.

Comment: What do you mean server-side to server-side? Are you trying to trigger a socket event from the server that the current server is already listening to? Wouldn't you just call the function if it's the same server?

Comment: @Deif yes, that would be a pratical solution, +1 thanks for pointing that out, so the socket.io would be a direct connection to the front-end socket and there's no way to trigger a process from serverside to serverside?

Comment: If you wanted to emit an event you would use the [event emitter](http://nodejs.org/api/events.html) module included in node. Socket.io is for client to server communication.

Comment: so we cannot use socket.on() to trigger other actions bound to socket? cuz wouldn't that be the clean way to do this?